# Power series whose coefficients are limits of coefficients of polynomial interpolations

Tags: polynomials, power-series, interpolation

When can you reconstruct the power series of a function by taking the limits of the coefficients of the polynomials that interpolate its values at $0,1,2,\dots,j$?

More precisely:

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  For all nonnegative integers $j$, let $p_j$ be the unique polynomial of degree $j$ with real coefficients such that $p_j(n)=f(n)$ for $n=0,\dots,j$.  Let $a_{j,k}$ be the coefficient of $x^k$ in $p_j$, where $a_{j,k}=0$ if $k>j$.  Under what circumstances do we have that $\lim_{j\to\infty} a_{j,k}$ exists for all $j$?  In this case, let $c_k=\lim_{j\to\infty} a_{j,k}$.  When $f$ is analytic, under what circumstances do we have that $f(x)=c_0+c_1 x+c_2 x^2 + c_3 x^3 +\cdots$?

Comment: You should specify where is your function analytic, and where your polynomials are supposed to converge. For entire $f$, theorems of this sort can be found in the book by A. Gelfond, Calculus of finite differences.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll take a look at that.

Comment: related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carlson%27s_theorem (condition for when $f$ is uniquely determined by $f(n)$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$) this only requires exponential type $\pi$ (not $\log(2)$)

Comment: See also: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.12846.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the paper,  A note on convergence of Newton interpolating polynomials,
by D. Dimitrov and J. Philipps, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics
Volume 51, Issue 1, 30 May 1994, Pages 127-130, the following simple criterion is mentioned: $f$ is entire of exponential type less than $\log 2$,
then the sequence of interpolation polynomials interpolating at non-negative integers converges to $f$.

Comment: Thanks!  Moreover, the Dimitrov / Phillips paper you mentioned has references to papers where that result is proved.